# BlobClient.OpenWriteAsync generates multiple BlobCreated events

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-eventgrid

I have a AzureFunction that is listen to BlobCreated Event that is triggered when a Blob is created in a container.

When I use the following code to create my blob from a string, I will get 1 BloblCreated Event generated.

```
    using var ms = new MemoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(content));
    ms.Position = 0;
    await blobClient.UploadAsync(ms, overwrite: true);
```

[image]

But this has some "unnecessary" memory usages that will be less if I use the following syntax to create my blob from my content string.

```
    using var stream = await blobClient.OpenWriteAsync(overwrite: true, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    using var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, encoding);
    await writer.WriteAsync(content);
```

The problem with the last code is that is generated 3 BloblCreated Event.

[image]

Is there a good reason to why the OpenWriteAsync() generates 3 events, and is there a way to "turn" this off, so it only generates 1 BlobCreated-event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing multiple `BlobCreated` events when using `OpenWriteAsync` is because the method creates the blob in three steps.

1. It sends a PUT request to create the blob.
2. And then sends a PUT request to set its properties (such as metadata).
3. Lastly it sends a PUT request to commit the blob. Each of these requests triggers a separate `BlobCreated` event.

> As for turning off the extra events, there isn't a way to do that with OpenWriteAsync.

You can use the `UploadAsync` method with a `BlockBlobUploadOptions` object that specifies the encoding and overwrite options. This avoids the extra events while still using the more memory-efficient approach.

```
using var stream = new MemoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(content));
await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, new BlobUploadOptions
{
    HttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = "text/plain" },
    Overwrite = true
});
```

This creates a `MemoryStream` from the content string and uses `UploadAsync` with a `BlobUploadOptions` object that specifies the content type and overwrite options. This approach should only generate one BlobCreated event.

**Another approach**

If you want to use `OpenWriteAsync`, you can disable the `BlobCreated` event for the first two stages by setting the `BlobRequestOptions` parameter to `DisableContentMD5Validation` and `DisableContentCrc64Validation` to `true`. This will disable the `BlobCreated` event for the first two stages, and only the final stage will generate the `BlobCreated` event.

To use `OpenWriteAsync` with `BlobRequestOptions` to disable the `BlobCreated` event for the first two stages.

```cs
using var stream = await blobClient.OpenWriteAsync(overwrite: true, cancellationToken: cancellationToken, options: new BlobRequestOptions { DisableContentMD5Validation = true, DisableContentCrc64Validation = true });
using var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, encoding);
await writer.WriteAsync(content);
```

For further information refer to [MSDoc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient.openwriteasync?view=azure-dotnet-preview)

Comment: Solution with setting BlobRequestOptions for OpenWriteAsync is no longer working. It's legacy now https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.blobrequestoptions?view=azure-dotnet-legacy